# how to use vite react app in vue js 2 app?

Tags: vuejs2, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, vite-reactjs, module-federationnextjs-mfutils

[it's my vue.config.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Sq5n.png)

[it's my webpack.config.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4aLU.png)

I have tried this and getting error,i have also added configs in webpack.config.js but it's not working
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJQcu.png)

i have tried both vue config's and webpack config's but both are not working.you can connect me on twitter or instagram (atulknowsme). I appreciate your help!

Comment: Do not show codes in screenshots.

Comment: Please read [ask] carefully.